# convert one type to another in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two references:

- in `.Core` reference I have one class with business functions.
- in another one - models, views and controllers.

I want to make a simple `Crete` function, but can not convert types.

```
//my model in .Core:

public class A
{ 
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}

//my Business function in .Core:

public void Add(A a)
    {
        using (My_Entities context = new My_Entities())
        {
            context.tS.Add(a);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }



//My ViewModel:

public class AViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}enter code here



//My controller:

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        AViewModel d= new AViewModel ();

        return PartialView("_Add", d);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(AViewModel a)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ABusiness sb = new ABusiness ();
           // sb.Add(a);


            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }


        return PartialView("_Add", a);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your database entity and not you business object. You can convert your business model to your entity model as you write to it.. example below. At least this is what Im assuming you are trying to do.

```
    public void Add(A a)
    {
        using (My_Entities context = new My_Entities())
        {
            context.tS.Add(new YourDatabaseEntity()
               {
                  Id = a.id,
                  Name = a.name
                  // etc..
               });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: My problem is when i try to call Add() function, i do not know how to pass A type. i mean in my Controeller i Have AViewModel, but in Business class function - public void Add(A a)